# Jquery - Initialize Select Box after first use

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

1. Page is loaded with a hidden select box in it.
2. I click on a button
3. I append elements to this select box, I move it and I make it visible
4. I apply plugin `Chosen` on it

This is done by this function

```
function moveHiddenSelect(idOffline, type, idMedia, mediaName){
    var $selToReplace  = $("#"+type+"_"+idOffline);
    var $selOriginal   = $("#originalSelect");
    $selToReplace.replaceWith($selOriginal);

    $.getScript('/lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js', function(){
        $selOriginal.chosen(); //load plugin script and apply it on the select box
    });

    $selOriginal.css("width", "220px");
    $selOriginal.css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

No problem when I click the button one time, but when I click again on the button (step 2) nothing is happend..

Comment: because on the second click your seltoreplace and seloriginal are the same elements. What do you expect to happen. If you want to switch back and forth between the elements you need test what is the actual element and depending on that make a replacement.

Comment: @SvenBieder that sounds like it deserves to be an answer rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chosen() should be called once, just for creation.
After updating the values of each dropdown, you could use: $(DropdoenElement).trigger("liszt:updated");

```
function moveHiddenSelect(idOffline, type, idMedia, mediaName){
    var $selToReplace  = $("#"+type+"_"+idOffline);
    var $selOriginal   = $("#originalSelect");
    $selToReplace.replaceWith($selOriginal);

    selOriginal.chosen(); // Init the plugin

    $.getScript('/lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js', function(){
       //load plugin script and apply it on the select box
       selOriginal.trigger("liszt:updated")
    });

    $selOriginal.css("width", "220px");
    $selOriginal.css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Hope it helps!